# Why is ember-data 2.7.0 normalizeHelper expecting a JSON API response from my custom adapter?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-local-storage

I have an ember-cli project which uses JSONAPI adapter, via `adapters/application.js`. I want to add a model class that should use the [`ember-localstorage-adapter`](https://github.com/locks/ember-localstorage-adapter). I declare the model and the respective adapter and serializer:

```
 models/widget.js
 import DS from 'ember-data';
 export default DS.Model.extend({...});

 adapters/widget.js
 import LSAdapter from 'ember-localstorage-adapter';
 export default LSAdapter.extend({});

 serializers/widget.js
 import LSSerializer from 'ember-localstorage-adapter';
 export default LSSerializer.extend({});
```

and load this models in my route:

```
 routes/index.js
 import Ember from 'ember';
 export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
      return this.store.findAll('widget');
    }
 });
```

This *should* work, but I get a missing function type error:

```
ember.debug.js:19755 TypeError: serializer.normalizeResponse is not a function
  at normalizeResponseHelper (serializer-response.js:80)
  at finders.js:147
  at Object.run (ember.debug.js:295)
  at Class._adapterRun (store.js:2056)
  at finders.js:146
  at tryCatch (ember.debug.js:52052)
  at invokeCallback (ember.debug.js:52067)
  at publish (ember.debug.js:52035)
  at ember.debug.js:41262
  at invoke (ember.debug.js:991)
```

OK, I add the missing method:

```
 serializers/widget.js
 import LSSerializer from 'ember-localstorage-adapter';
 export default LSSerializer.extend({
   normalizeResponse: function(store, modelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
     return payload;
   }
 });
```

And now the error is about the payload:

```
 ember.debug.js:19755 Error: Assertion Failed: normalizeResponse must return a valid JSON API document:
    * One or more of the following keys must be present: "data", "errors", "meta".
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.EmberError (../assets/vendor.js:30247:21)
    at assert (../assets/vendor.js:17276:13)
    at Object.assert (../assets/vendor.js:30059:34)
    at assert (../assets/vendor.js:97498:37)
    at normalizeResponseHelper (../assets/vendor.js:107520:39)
```

Why is this asserted? Can't I mix and match a JSON API adapter with a non-conforming one? I understand there could be problems if the models would try to intreact (eg. has-one/belongs-to etc relationships) but there is no such thing. I'm just trying to add a new model that is not backed by my back-end (JSON-API conforming) REST api.

Ember: 2.7.2
Embed Data: 2.7.0

Comment: BTW, I understand that simply returning `{data: payload}` would make my payload JSON-API compliant, my question is not *how*, but *why*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your import is wrong!

Its not

```
import LSSerializer from 'ember-localstorage-adapter';
```

but

```
import {LSSerializer} from 'ember-localstorage-adapter';
```

This is because of the exports in `ember-localstorage-adapter`:

```
import LSAdapter from 'ember-localstorage-adapter/adapters/ls-adapter';
import LSSerializer from 'ember-localstorage-adapter/serializers/ls-serializer';

export {
  LSAdapter,
  LSSerializer
};

export default LSAdapter;
```

With `import LSSerializer from 'ember-localstorage-adapter';` you import the `default` export wich is not the serializer.

Next you need to understand that `ember-data` internally works with `JSONAPI` documents. Its the function of the serializer to serialize whatever the adapter is fetching into `JSONAPI`. This is defined by the `store` and `ember-data` itself. See the [API specification](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_push).

Not lets see what this code from you is doing:

```
serializers/widget.js
import LSSerializer from 'ember-localstorage-adapter';

export default LSSerializer.extend({
    normalizeResponse: function(store, modelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
        return payload;
    }
});
```

You are actually returning an adapter where you implement the `normalizeResponse` function. That makes it an valid serializer, that is doing nothing! You directly return what is responded by your adapter, which seems to be not valid JSONAPI. Thats why this error occurs.

Comment: Thanks, the `import {LSSerializer}` actually explains a lot of the funky behavior I was seeing. I was using the adapter as the serializer, I had to implement `serialize` on it because it wasn't actually a serializer... d'oh. Now it all works out-of-the-box. As for the JSONAPI being the de-facto internal format, I didn't know that, but it all make sense now.